# Find the arclength of $y=4x^2+2$ on the interval $ [0,2]$

Tags: calculus

This is my work so far.

$y=4x^2+2$

$f(x)=4x^2+2$

$f'(x)=8x$

$\int_0^2\sqrt{1+(8x)^2}dx$

$\int_0^2\sqrt{1+64x^2}dx$

$\int_8^{16}\sqrt{u^2+a^2}du$

Comment: think of $tan^t+1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: Put $x = \dfrac{\tan u}{8}$